# How to prevent android and ios font settings to bold / larger font size in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

When changing the font to bold in the device some of the labels are overlapping and the text will be bold. also, when we change font size it also affects the Ui.

Comment: Just set a fixed size for the font?

Comment: I am not sure how do you change the font to bold. But, you could change the label size when you change the font to bold.